# Abrir um diretório e executar uma ação PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando mudar o diretório atual para outro e assim conseguir executar uma ação. O script abaixo está funcionando, porém só no diretório raiz. Gostaria de abrir, exemplo o `/temp` executar e depois sair novamente.

```
$comando="verifica_licenca.exe -v -f licencas$cnpj.dat";

//Executa o comando para verificar licença e armazena na variavel $line

$licencas = exec(escapeshellcmd($comando), $output);

reset($output);

while (list(,$line) = each($output)){

//Grava resultado da execução da execução no banco de dados

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexao, "INSERT INTO licenca (cnpj,dados, data) VALUES(?,?,?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $cnpj, $line, $data);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

}
```

Agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Você quer executar o arquivo `verifica_licenca.exe` em vários diretórios? Se for isso, utilize o caminho absoluto, por exemplo: `C:\\Users\\user\\path\\to\\verifica_licenca.exe -v -f ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem duas formas de mudar o diretório para `exec`:

#### chdir

Usando a função [chdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php)

```
$comando="verifica_licenca.exe -v -f licencas$cnpj.dat";

$path="c:\caminho\para\verifica\licenca\";

chdir($path); 

//Executa o comando para verificar licença e armazena na variavel $line

$licencas = exec(escapeshellcmd($comando), $output);
```

#### comando cd

Você pode incluir o `cd` no seu comando:

```
$comando="cd \caminho\para\verifica\licenca\; verifica_licenca.exe -v -f licencas$cnpj.dat";

//Executa o comando para verificar licença e armazena na variavel $line

$licencas = exec(escapeshellcmd($comando), $output);
```

Comment: Oi Ricardo, consegui resolver usando o chdir, muito obrigado!